# Spring Boot Implementing Swagger not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, swagger

Hey i just want to implement swagger, however when i add the dependency in maven:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And run the application it shows me this error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.example.BlogApplicationRestApi.BlogApplicationRestApiApplication.main(BlogApplicationRestApiApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
```

Any suggestions how can i fix this bug?

Comment: This is to less information to spot the problem. You should add at least the relevant parts of you pom (so that one know dependency version) and the Spring configuration.

Comment: If you are using Spring Security, use the security configuration mentioned on **[Cannot open Swagger UI in tis Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-tis-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example)** page.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue by changing project version: from 2.6.3 to 2.4.2